# How do you pass a function from one react component to another in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the the parent component I have. Which is connected to redux so it has its own state/dispatch/props.

```
<Home_User_Dash
     handleEditOpen={this.handleEditOpen.bind(this)}
     handleEditClose={this.handleEditClose.bind(this)}
/>
```

Although when trying to use the method in the child component I get this error message

```
HandleEditOpen does not exist on type'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<HomeUserProps>
```

### EDIT 1 more info

HandleEditOpen and close are just the inverse of each other.

```
public handleEditOpen() {
    this.setState({editTruckId: true});
}
```

the connect method, both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are different on both components. When logging the incoming state on the child component there is no `handleEditOpen` or close.

```
export const Home_Dash = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

If I remove the typings on the connect method of HomeUser then the I get this error message from the Home component on the method being passed.

```
handleEditOpen does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ children...'
```

#### Update

When removing all references to the parent methods and running the page and outputting the props they show up on the component. This seems to be a purely Typescript typing issue between components. Not that Typescript has a problem but I am un-aware of how to type the child component correctly.

### Solved?

I was able to finally have the method passed in without typing issues. It turns out that I needed to pass the methods as this.

```
<Home_User_Dash
     handleEditOpen={() => this.handleEditOpen.bind(this)}
     handleEditClose={() => this.handleEditClose.bind(this)}
/>
```

And for the types needed to not have the method being passed in the connect types. It needed to be added on the class itself as such.

```
interface IHomeUserProps {
    users: Iuser[];
    users_error: string;
}

interface IHomeUserInjectedProps {
    handleEditOpen: () => any;
    handleEditClose: () => any;
}

interface IHomeUserDispatchProps {
    fetchAllUsers: () => any;
}

interface IHomeUserState {
    username: string | null;
    user: Iuser | null;
    populated: boolean;
}

type HomeUserProps = IHomeUserDispatchProps & IHomeUserProps & IHomeUserInjectedProps;

class HomeUser extends Component<HomeUserProps, IHomeUserState> {
```

and the connect method

```
export const Home_User_Dash = connect<IHomeUserProps, IHomeUserDispatchProps, IHomeUserInjectedProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeUser);
```

Comment: Please show us `handleEditOpen` definition.

Comment: Does `HomeUserProps` define `handleEditOpen` and `handleEditClose`? Or, conversely, does the error go away if you (temporarily) change the props' type to `any`?

Comment: @shabs yes if I add in a description of the incoming method the all errors go away. Although, the method is not coming in. Logging the props and even trying to load the page fails saying that the method does not exist.

Comment: @mjwrazor We'll need minimal reproducible snippet illustrating your problem

Comment: @ManasJayanth I have never made a snippet for typescript or know how. But the issue is that I can't send a method of one component to another component that it is rendering.

Comment: @mjwrazor I understand your concern. Try using create-react-app typescript starter. In App.tsx file create a small parent-child component and see if the problem is seen there. If so, post it here. It's easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter

Comment: @ManasJayanth that doesn't have an example of passing a method to another component.